# How to obtain updated co-ordinates from matrix after applying transform and scale in OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, matrix

I am applying some transform and scaling on opengl layer in iPhone. All I want to know is is there any api to retrieve rectangle co-ordinates after applying glTranform and glScale?

I found one api `glGetFloatV(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix)`. This api returns array of 16 elements describing matrix information. Can I retrieve updated coordinates from this? Is there any other api which can help?

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.0. its an old project.

Comment: OpenGL ES 1.0 is not deprecated. `EAGLContext` still provides the valid `EAGLRenderingAPI` for `kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/opengles/reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/EAGLRenderingAPI

Comment: @CaptainRedmuff That EAGLContext provides it is just for backwards compatibility. But ES 1.0 should not be used anymore for many reasons.

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation does it state that OpenGL ES 1.0 is deprecated nor should it be avoided.

Comment: [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESontheiPhone/OpenGLESontheiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH101-SW11): "If you are maintaining an OpenGL ES 1.1 app, you should consider updating your code for newer OpenGL ES versions."

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. Even if it was, it may not be the best option for your application as it would mean retrieving data back from the GPU.

The easiest solution would be to perform the same transformations within your program on the CPU, for example by implementing matrix multiplication functions.

If you don't have time to re-invent the wheel, there is a library called [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html) which would allow you to do matrix multiplication and it's specifically based on OpenGL - so it shouldn't be too hard for you to use. All you will have to do is create the same transformation matrix that you are using currently, except you'll do it with GLM functions instead of (or in addition to) the OpenGL functions. Then you just multiply your desired rectangle vertices with the GLM matrix to get your transformed points.

Just keep in mind that, with this method, if you are intending to transform a lot of vertices you will run into performance issues (because you will be doing the transformations sequentially on the CPU, rather than in parallel on the GPU). If you're only looking to get the transformed vertices of a few rectangles though, this should be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS the easiest thing to do is probably use the `GLKMathProject` function. The function signature looks like this:

```
GLKVector3 GLKMathProject(GLKVector3 object, GLKMatrix4 model, GLKMatrix4 projection, int *viewport);
```

To use it, you'll need:

- The coordinates you want to transform are in object. You'll transform one coordinate of your rectangle at a time.
- The model view matrix, which you'll get with the `glGetFloatv` call as you mentioned. You need to turn it into a GLKMatrix4 (see below).
- The projection matrix, which you also get with `glGetFloatv`, but with the `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` parameter.
- The coordinates of the viewport, which is where in the window you are drawing to. If you have not called glViewport then the viewport is an int array with elements [0, 0, width of window, height of window] in it.

To get the matrix as the GLKMatrix4 you should be able to do something like this:

```
GLMatrix4 modelviewMat;
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelviewMat.m);
```

Hope this helps! The GLM library is also useful, but if you use GLKit you won't have to add any other files to your project, just import the GLKit framework.